# Can we add d10 and d4 support to the chat dice bot?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Our current chat dice bot is awesome. However it could be more awesome with 3 things.

The first and most important is support both the d4 and the d10. Currently these die rolls can be resolved using other dies but native support would be really good. (d3 would also be great, but is not necessary)

The second thing that would be really awesome would be support for fudge dice. (These are six sided dice that have 2 sides showing a '+', 2 sides showing a '-' and 2 blank sides)

The final thing that would be most helpful would be support for larger dice pools. Currently it is limited at 9. Support for up to 12 would be nice.

(Edit from Brian)

To extend and amplify, being one of the people who use this in chat for real games, the red dice visualization is cute but distracting. Ultimately, I would love this to present a [`rolldice`](http://dev.man-online.org/man6/rolldice/) like syntax (but including fudge dice) or similar which supports strong dice expressions. A port or hook to [troll](http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp) could also be effective as a tool that can be referenced in dice questions. But the giant red dice, while eye catching, aren't particularly useful when actually gaming with them. Having a direct rolldice link would be awesome, especially if it pulled from /dev/random

(Edit from Max)

Dice are a major part of most RPG games and having a flexible dice system could encourage more visitors to the chat. Being able to type 'roll XdY +/- Z' would be marvelous. I would like to see it display the individual rolls as well as the sum in the output if possible.

(Community Syntax)

`{#x}{#}d[#|%|f]{[+|-]#}`

{#x} optional, roll # sets

{#}d[#|%|f] amount not required, defaults to 1, sides required, number, % (percentile), f (fudge, with +,-, and blank)

{[+|-]#} add or subtract a number

output:

Text as Individual dice, total rolled via text format. preserve current images for the trivial #d# expressions supported.

Comment: There exist many dice apps already written that should be trivial to adapt, depending on the language of the stack.

Comment: Until the chat dice bot gets all features you want, you could use http://rolz.org/. It's pretty much the most awesome online dice roller I've seen so far with its extensive list of options, custom rooms, macros and the ability to embed rolls as images elsewhere.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting these out.  I'd wager that adding d4/d10 is easier than the other two.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, d4 and d10 are my graduation gift to you :) They will be available with the launch of the [new site design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se). Since that's the main part of the request, I'm tagging it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Now, as far as the rest goes, I have to decline that. The dice bot is supposed to be a cute little chat room easter egg unique to the RPG rooms. Its purpose is not (and never was intended to be, and never will be) to be a full-fledged feature-complete dice rolling service that covers all possible variations.

This has nothing to do with the question whether it's easy to implement, or whether someone takes the time to write the code. The plain and simple reason is that it's requesting to turn the dice bot into something that it's not supposed to be.

This would be reason enough, but [Brian gave me another great reason](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4165336#4165336):

> [...] it's generally quite convienent to have it be a dice-roller while we chat on skype, etc.

Uhm, yeah, it should be quite obvious that that's *not* a supported use case; on the contrary, I'm quite unhappy to see that happening. And that's not just because it creates transcripts like [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3564982#3564982).

Comment: Thanks for the common dice, and agreed on the use case and further support.

Comment: Thanks! for the expansion!

Comment: @C.Ross come to chat good news!

Comment: @balpha Thanks!