# Promoting our site launch?

Tags: discussion, design

Hopefully by now you've seen [Jin](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75/jin)'s **Awesome** [Design for RPG.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se), so you know we're moving toward a launch.  The question is, how can we make the launch as successful as possible?  How and where can we promote this launch?

Comment: Do we have a budget or should we just assume it needs to be community driven/free?

Comment: To some extent, much of what was discussed in [CHAOS is here! How can we help?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/chaos-is-here-how-can-we-help) is relevant here.

Answer (score 7):

We should have every RPG.SE poster promote the launch on:

1. Forums they frequent (wizards, rpg.net, enworld, dragonsfoot, paizo, storygames, therpgsite)
2. Their blog
3. Their social media of choice

But, of course, we've been saying that all along and have gotten indifferent results.

Ideally we'd have a little $$ to hook it into some cheap banner ads on enworld/rpg.net, heck buy a google adword or two.  Buying an ad in the Gen Con con booklet. That sort of thing.  Cheap but not free.

Comment: There is indeed a budget for this, and I think all of this is great. I actually trust our users to know more about what sites are relevant and possibly get information about banner costs from them. If users want to scout out sites and rates and give that info to me, I will gladly get the advertising ball rolling. In the meantime, I'm sure Jin could whip up a cool banner that you guys could put (like a badge of honor) on your personal blogs/sites/social media, etc.

Comment: Gen Con 2012 booklet: $900 for a half page. http://www.gencon.com/2012/indy/sm/eventmarketing/printads.aspx It's the Cadillac of cons, smaller but still large cons like DragonCon are half that (http://advertising.dragoncon.org/2012-rate-card-2/).

Comment: ENWorld doesn't advertise their prices, will have to contact: http://www.enworld.org/index.php?page=ads

Comment: Also I'm not sure how giving freebies works.  A lot of cons (well, work cons, and probably GC/DC) like hand out bags with ads and trinkets in them, I assume the supplier provides the trinkets and pays something on top of that, might be a good distribution method for rpg.se trinkets/cups/dice bags/whatever someone does from that meta q.

Answer (score 1):

If we could get a group together and get a table on the floor at DragonCon (or sponser a game or two?) that would be really good.

I know we have several users (including myself) who are within a reasonable travel radius for the event and that would be a great way to do some low level on the ground type promotion. (If this was supplemented by a program ad that would be cool).