# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se).

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the follow urls and do a hard browser refresh.

http://sstatic.net/rpg/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/rpgmeta/img/favicon.ico

We have also themed the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/the-game-table), [twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/stackrpg) account and newsletter template for this site.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Very awesome!!!

Comment: Awesome!  I no longer want to keep sketchy.  http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/can-we-keep-sketchy

Comment: Whoa! I wasn't expecting that!

Comment: This looks awesome! Hooray!

Comment: I like the new look very much

Comment: Amazing stuff. How does one get the iOS home screen icon for the page to change from the RP speech bubble to whatever-it-is-now?

Comment: @Jadasc i think the old Apple touch icon was cached. I'm not sure how you refresh on iOS. Maybe delete it and re-add?

Comment: @Jin "Delete-then-add" doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Huzzah!  The new title graphic has sort of a retro Gamma World thing going on!

Comment: Hey, is the mobile theme going to change?  It's still all blue and simple.

Comment: @mxyzplk The mobile same is shared between all sites, including e.g. Stack Overflow.

Comment: Very nice, congrats to the designers!  I love how it has both fantasy and sci-fi elements, while remaining beautifully legible.  Looks like a million GP :)

Comment: I sought this question out simply to voice my opinion on the details of the new layout. Outstanding! I have not logged on in sometime. It was a most pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 6):

Whoa! Superb. I was all about sketchy until I saw this.

Comment: That's 2 of us!