# Welcome banner not seen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I am not seeing the welcome banner as show on the [design for RPG.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se) .  Is it my browser (Chrome) or something that is not yet done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see it just fine.

My guess is that you have only looked at the site while logged in, correct? The welcome banner is only shown to anonymous users. Open RPG.se in an incognito window (Ctrl-Shift-N) and you should see it.

Comment: That is correct.  Thank you for pointing this out.