# What does this site's logo mean?

Tags: discussion, design

Hey could you tell me a little bit about your logo and what it means? I really like it.

Same one that appears as the Favicon in the URL field and behind the word playing in the banner.

Answer (score 11):

The designer, Jin, explained a bit about it in the original post about it, [Design for RPG.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se):

> I'm also subtly using dice as recurring visual elements throughout the site, as seen as the logo, accepted answer background and voting arrows.

The hexagon divided into triangles invokes the shape of a [20-sided die](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/d20) — one of the most common dice that is still distinctive to roleplaying games — seen top-down and rendered with a subtle amount of perspective.

Compare:

[image: The RPG SE logo on its own without text: a stylised twenty-sided die inside a circle]
[image: A black twenty-sided die with gold numbering]

Comment: [This image](http://cs4.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2014-11_4/141624940673.jpg) perhaps more directly shows how the icon matches the d20: it’s oriented the same way, so you can see how each triangle in the logo appears just the same way when viewed head-on like this.