# Where does the header banner image come from?

Tags: support, design

I mean the image of the androids fighting the dragon above.

It looks cool.

Where does it come from?

Answer (score 12):

The header graphic is an original artwork by [Dean Spencer](https://www.deanspencerart.com), commissioned for RPG.se. It hasn't been used anywhere else.

You can read more about our design in the original announcement unveiling the site's graphic design: [Design for RPG.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se).

Comment: Thank you! That's really damn cool image! I'd give the guy who made it a high five if i knew him in real life!