# New RPG.SE theme coming this summer

Tags: discussion, site-design

The entire [SE Network is going through some redesign this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/311001). TL;DR: giving each site a really nicely-tuned theme (color scheme, iconography, artwork) wasn't a sustainable model. This greatly slowed down some navigation redesign that's rolling out, and made adding features and fixing bugs across the network a nightmare for the devs, so themes are being stripped down.

[The first group of redesigns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365/311001) just went live. There's your chance to see what level of differentiation is still being preserved and what the new left-navigation menus will look like. And imagine how much of [RPGSE's design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1416/23970) will persist or not.

If you have questions, concerns, or suggestions about what's coming I **strongly** suggest you read up on the network-wide meta Q&As linked above (and further linked from those) and comment/answer there. We--local elected moderators--have no influence on this process beyond what any meta.SE poster would. (Many of you greatly out-rep me on meta.SE, for instance!) I'm only posting here in hopes of making the upcoming change less of a surprise to RPGSE users who may not follow meta.SE activity.

Lastly, I would like to take a point of privilege to thank [Jin](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75/jin) for the work they did assembling this awesome design in the first instance. **Thank you, Jin!!!**

Comment: And this is why we drink.  Thanks for the alert, I see that KRyan and doppelgreene have been out there fighting the good fight already.

Comment: Well sigh. They really did a number on TeX; that does not bode well for us. I really do not feel that these changes have been well-communicated—they seem arbitrary and unnecessary for the goal of allowing more uniform and streamlined updates. They keep asserting that they are necessary, but *why* they are necessary remains completely unclear to me (a professional web developer).

Comment: @KRyan: Reminds me of all the verbiage around their assorted legal updates the last few years… "Trust us, we've had some very good legal experts look all this over and tell us exactly what we need and work out all the details." "What about this? And also this other? And did you consider the effect of EU law on this aspect? How about this knock-on effect?" "Er, we'll have our legal guys look those over and get back to you in a couple days!" When SE says that such-and-such cheese-moving is absolutely unimpeachable from a professional standpoint, it's time to break out the unimpressed looks.

Comment: Does Reddit face the same problem(s) when upgrading site features against a sub-reddit's theme?

Comment: @Jason_c_o I don’t believe it does. Reddit also allows sub-reddits to produce their own theming, which is kind of neat. SE is going in a very different direction, pushing the network towards greater homogeneity—supposedly because it makes things easier to maintain and update (and some of it does, undoubtedly), but likely there are other ulterior motives at play (read: someone thinks it will somehow improve their money-making ability). Which I wouldn’t even mind, if I actually believed it would have that effect. But I don’t.

Comment: I hope it's just my machine, but the sticky bar covers my upvote button when jumping to a new answer from the question index. [Seriously?](https://www.amazon.com/We-Didnt-Playtest-This-All/dp/B00SXO5DES)

Comment: @HeyICanChan [It's not just you.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312527/152515) :(

Comment: @KRyan That's kinda what I meant. I didn't actually believe it would/is causing the problems they claim...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast *Disable top bar stickiness* is now an available tickbox in your profile under settings.

Comment: I think a separate meta "announcing" the stickiness and where that setting is would make sense. I'm on the road for a few days and won't get to it before Monday so anyone should feel free to put such together if they're motivated.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, I fixed it a few hours ago.  Thx.