# Can the main theme picture of the site be changed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I haven't been on this website for a while but i could say i've been here for about a year and i noticed the picture of the Dragon fighting some people. I've been looking at it for a year and it kinda feels not RPG to me (maybe i'm wrong).

[image]

I think changing it would be cool and new because this one looks really old and kind of weird. Could some dice or pen or even knights be added or is this the logo of the website?
Even i cold make it, it's not that hard. Even a black-and-white type for the Meta could be easy to make. Or is this one staying?

Comment: It is good to note that voting is a bit different on meta. For feature requests, upvoting means you agree with the proposal and downvoting means the reverse. Just so you know how to interpret the voting.

Comment: You might get a bit more traction for this if you explain why it feels "not RPG" to you. You may find [this post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1416/4398) useful history to read; the image was created as "a mix of traditional D&D and sci-fi genre" to reflect that RPGs cover much more diverse than just high-magic fantasy.

Comment: For what it's worth, RPG.SE is upcoming in the list for a new design as part of [Stack Exchange's redesign campaign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/389635)

Answer (score 8):

## The top image is staying

As we can see with [the new beta site theme](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8391) preview, we're keeping it:

[image: Screenshot of the RPG.se front page, showing the top art still prominent.]

The top image is an original artwork by artist [Dean Spencer](http://www.satedcanvas.com/), commissioned [specifically for RPG.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/design-for-rpg-se) at the cost of real dollars. We've had it ever since we had a site design at all: six years. SE won't be buying new art for RPG.se every year (and probably never).

Answer (score 6):

While the image features a juxtaposition of fantasy (the dragon) and sci-fi (the people shooting it with a laser), nothing about that makes me think "not RPG". It certainly isn't a scene that would commonly occur in the most popular RPG series, Dungeons and Dragons, and I would be that the in the majority of RPGs that juxtaposition is unusual for one reason or another, but the site isn't about any single RPG. Instead, both fantasy and sci-fi RPGs are valid here, as well as others, and having a mix is appropriate for that.

Note that I can only really guess at what feels "not RPG" about it to you. As for myself, the banner looks like several images taken straight out of various RPG source books and composited together.

Answer (score 2):

## I like it

There are [good reasons it’s not likely to change](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8394/4563), [good reasons why it actually does befit RPG SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8389/4563), but ultimately, I think the most important thing for me is, *I like it.* And I think a lot of other people do too. RPG SE is often touted as one of the best designs on the network.

I like that it’s a little weird, a little different from what you might expect. That makes it feel unique, *ours*. And I like that it isn’t just swords and sorcery—after all, the RPG landscape is bigger than just swords and sorcery, *too*, and it’s both good to acknowledge that and also, it’s good to maybe give a little hint to those who might not be aware of it.

Comment: I made a mistake declining your recent flag--I saw the moment the overlay closed the sentence or two that are obviously rude. Pointing the other mods at it now, and thanks for the flag.

Comment: @nitsua60 Please take particular care regarding flags against that particular user—he has a long, long history of rude and abusive behavior, and while the Stack Exchange software absolutely sucks for documenting that fact, we should at least have the trail of Helpful rude or abusive flags. If we had more transparency and better tools for accumulating data and evidence, I have no doubt that user should have been long-since banned from this site, with prejudice.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I'm going to resubmit, actually, on that post just so that it does get gathered into the under-the-hood collection area for flags against users. Excelsior!