# New dice mode in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

It would be helpful if there was a dice mode for Fudge dice. Fudge dice are 6 sided, with 2 +, 2 -, and two blank. It would even be cooler if the total would be added together (+1, -1, 0) and given. Two suggestions on how to have this be called.

4dF (Rolls 4 fudge dice)

Fudge! (Same as 4df)

There are those who have a script to change the dice automatically, but it would be nice to support, especially since there seems to be a fair amount of chat room activity revolving around Fate, which uses Fudge dice.

Comment: [The script in question](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/169427) is currently at the "kludge" stage and would require some streamlining before it could be adopted, but I'm providing it for context. I support an xdf implementation; conceivably someone might want to roll more or less than four at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting myself from [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/can-we-add-d10-and-d4-support-to-the-chat-dice-bot/1422#1422):

> […] I have to decline that. The dice bot is supposed to be a cute little chat room easter egg unique to the RPG rooms. Its purpose is not (and never was intended to be, and never will be) to be a full-fledged feature-complete dice rolling service that covers all possible variations.
>
> This has nothing to do with the question wether it's easy to implement, or whether someone takes the time to write the code. The plain and simple reason is that it's requesting to turn the dice bot into some that it's not supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for the response. :) And for the d6's we got to turn into fate dice.